# Is there a way to 'search' in a pandas DataFrame for 2 specific numbers in columns and return the index if it exists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a made a DataFrame using pandas and want to know if there is a way to 'search' for 2 specific numbers in the rows of specific columns and then return the row

eg

[image: eg]

seach if a = 4 and b =6 return 1 (the index)

or if b=5 and c =2  return 2 (the index)

or seach in a = 2 and b=1 return nothing. (as this does not exist)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(df.loc[(df["A"] == 4) & (df["B"] == 6)].index[0])
```

In a function:

```
def pairs(df, k1,k2, a, b):
    check = df.loc[(df[k1] == a) & (df[k2] == b)]
    return None if check.empty else check.index[0]
```

Running it on your df:

```
In [5]: pairs(df,"A","B",4,6)
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: pairs(df,"B","C",5,2 )
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: print(pairs(df,"A","B",2,1))
None
```

If you want all indexes use index.tolist:

```
def pairs(df, k1,k2, a, b):
    check = df.loc[(df[k1] == a) & (df[k2] == b)]
    return None if check.empty else check.index.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks! The only issue I see with this is it thows an error if you where to try say,

print(df.loc[(df["A"] == 10) & (df["B"] == 0)].index[0])

as this does not exist

Comment: @AlexTreacher, that is because Index is empty, that is what `check.empty` catches

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most effective way, so please feel free to correct me but.

def find(a,b):

```
n = 0 
while n < len(df.index):
    if df.iloc[n]['a'] == a and df.iloc[n]['b'] == b:
        print n
    n += 1
```